# Intercept MyTouch 4g genius button

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to intercept the genius button on the new MyTouch 4g by HTC?  Is it somehow hard wired to the kernel?

I looked at logCat, and I see that if uses the following intent:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(1309): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp/.VSuiteStartSession }
```

UPDATE:
I've seen another app disable the genius button on non-rooted phones, so it seems possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this has been done with a guide on XDA.  You will have to Root the phone.  I don't know of a non-root solution.

Here's the link to the guide:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=836702&highlight=genius